# Как получить содержимое из TextField в слое С++?

Tags: qt, qt5, qml, qtquick

В слое QML есть TextField:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1


Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 310
    maximumHeight: height
    maximumWidth: width
    minimumHeight: height
    minimumWidth: width
    title: qsTr("")

    Connections {
        target: backend  

        onSendToQml: {
          console.log("QML " + count); 
        }
    } 
    
    TextField {
        id: textField
        objectName: "sp"
        x: 9
        y: 36
    } 

    Switch {
        id: control
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 300
        height: 50
        text: qsTr("")
        checked: false

        onClicked: {
            backend.setBackend(control);
        }

        contentItem: Text {
            rightPadding: control.indicator.width + control.spacing
            text: control.text
            font: control.font
            opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3

            color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
            elide: Text.ElideRight
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }

        indicator: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 48
            implicitHeight: 26
            x: control.width - width - control.rightPadding
            y: parent.height / 2 - height / 2
            radius: 13
            color: control.checked ? "#17a81a" : "transparent"
            border.color: control.checked ? "#17a81a" : "#cccccc"

            Rectangle {
                x: control.checked ? parent.width - width : 0
                width: 26
                height: 26
                radius: 13
                color: control.down ? "#cccccc" : "#ffffff"
                border.color: control.checked ? (control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b") : "#999999"
            }
        }

        background: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 40
            visible: control.down /*|| control.highlighted*/
            color: control.down ? "#bdbebf" : "#eeeeee"
        }
    }
}
```

не как не могу получить данные из него в слое С++
при использование данного кода

C++

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "backend.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    BackEnd backend;  

    QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();
    context->setContextProperty("backend", &backend); 
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"))); 
    return -1;

    return app.exec();
 }
```

backend.h

```
#ifndef BACKEND_H
#define BACKEND_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class BackEnd : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit BackEnd(QObject *parent = 0);

signals: 
    void sendToQml(int count);

private slots: 
    void setBackend(bool control);

public: 
};

#endif // BACKEND_H
```

bakend.cpp

```
#include "backend.h"
#include <iostream>

BackEnd::BackEnd(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

void BackEnd::setBackend(bool control) 
{       
    if(control){
        //Найдем строки ввода
        QObject* field1 = this->parent()->findChild<QObject*>("sp");

        //Считаем информацию со строк ввода через свойство text
        QString str1=(field1->property("text")).toString();
   
        //  std::cout << str1 << std::endl ;
    }
}
```

пишет

> Программа неожиданно завершилась.
>
> Процесс был завершён принудительно.

Comment: Приведите весь код полностью.

Comment: @mkkik добавил.

Comment: Вы где-то видели пример использования такого метода передачи данных `QML -> C++`?

Comment: @mkkik я вас не понял. Вы про лямбда выражение ?

Comment: Про это `QObject* field1 = this->parent()->findChild<QObject*>("sp");`. Посмотрите примеры из [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html)

Comment: @mkkik честно пример из доков не совсем понятен что он даёт. Результат его работы это окно с TextField.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78292/discussion-between-varg-sieg-and-mkkik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Программа неожиданно завершилась из-за этого места:

```
//...
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"))); 
return -1;

return app.exec();
```

Вы, видимо, случайно удалили строку (после load(...)):

```
if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
    return -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

import Binder 1.0

Item {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Binder {
        id: obj
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        TextField {
            id: tf
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        }
        Button{
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            text: "Send"
            onClicked: {
                obj.onSend(tf.text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickView>


class Binder: public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void onSend(QString s) {
        qDebug() << s;
    }
 };


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<Binder>("Binder", 1, 0, "Binder");

    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```